# UITableViewWrapperView size is not changing as per the content if row height is UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

`UITableViewWrapperView` size is not changing as per the content if row height is `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

I am trying to create a Feed listing with TableView and dynamic height rows.
TableView is scrollable but `UITableViewWrapperView` looks like it's not changing its size!

Below is the code and screenshot of the view hierarchy.

I think its strange.

Code:

```
class FeedController: UITableViewController {

    var items: NSMutableArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "feedLoad", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        self.feedLoad()

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120.0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        println("called")
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return self.getCellForItemAtIndexPath( indexPath )
    }

    func getCellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let item: Dictionary = self.items[indexPath.row] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( (item["type"] as String) + "Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath ) as FeedViewCell

        cell.fillData(item)

        return cell as UITableViewCell
    }

    func feedLoaded(){

        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func feedLoad(){
        // Feed Load Logic which will call next line once feed loaded

        self.feedLoaded()
    }

}
```

[image: View Hierarchy]

Comment: I'm having the same issue & still cannot find an answer to it.

Comment: What are your constraints?

Comment: have same issue , did you solved that?

Comment: Does heightForRowAtIndexPath() get called?

Comment: can you put screenshot of constraint which are applied to tableviewcell.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have auto layout configured for your cell, as that's the only way to get this working. Auto Layout should be able to calculate the height based on your cell constraints.

So you should have constraints between your views vertically and between the views on the top and bottom edges the super view (in this case the cell view).

Suppose you have a cell with title and description, like this:

```
|------------------|
| Title            |
|                  |
| Description with |
| long multiple    |
| lines of text    |
|------------------|
```

In this example you have to set add a constraint with a vertical space between `title` and `description`, a constraint of vertical space between the `title`'s top and the cell view top and a vertical space between the `description`'s bottom and the cell view's bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath() says that the value retuned by that call is the placeholder value for all till a scroll event occurs. I am guessing that when the scroll even does occur, heightForRowAtIndexPath will get called. So:

1. Change the value for estimated height and see if that is the fixed
   height that you observe.
2. Does heightForRow get called when you scroll? If not, may be there are other    issues about scrolling, such as contentSize etc., that need addressing so that scrolling does take place.

Answer (score 0):

When you using **automaticDimention**, You should add constraints to both sides of UILabels in **UItableViewCell**.